# Change subtitle dynamically video - HTML5

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video

I am trying to change the subtitle tracks dynamically on button click using the following lines of code.But it is not changing the subtitles.why?

```js
$('#turnoff').click(function(){
  $('.player-content-video track').attr('default',false);
});

$('#english').click(function(){
  $('.player-content-video track').attr('default',false);
   $('.player-content-video track').eq(0).attr('default',false);
});

$('#chinese').click(function(){
   $('.player-content-video track').eq(1).attr('default',false);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<video class="player-content-video">
  <track src="sample_video-en.vtt" srclang="en" kind="subtitles" default="true">
  <track src="sample_video-ch.vtt" default="false" srclang="ch" kind="subtitles">
  <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
<br/>
<button id="turnoff" >NO SUBTITLE</button>
<button id="english" >ENGLISH</button>
<button id="chinese" >CHINESE</button>
```

**NOTE:** The `track` `src` in this example is only for code demonstration.

Comment: Check the MDN article on this subject https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Apps/Fundamentals/Audio_and_video_delivery/Adding_captions_and_subtitles_to_HTML5_video#Subtitle_implementation you will need to change the `mode` of items in the `video.textTracks` array property

Comment: Note, source of `track` element at stacksnippets is not full path

Comment: The trach src is only for demonstration

Answer (score 4):

If you need to change the `default` attribute on your `track` tag you could use the following script:

Working example, please inspect the DOM to see the result (as video and track src are not present):

https://jsfiddle.net/3hh9kvgd/

You can use jQuery `:eq() Selector` in the following way.
[More info can be found here.](https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/)

`$('.player-content-video track:eq(0)')`

By the way using `:eq()` make your code dependent of your `<track>` position in the DOM and require transverse all DOM when User click on a button, which is not really good approach in term maintainability and perfomance.

You could instead, reference your `<track>` by id and cache your DOM selection when using jQuery.

---

```
    $('#turnoff').click(function(){
       $('.player-content-video track').attr('default',false);
    });

    $('#english').click(function(){
       $('.player-content-video track').attr('default',false);
       $('.player-content-video track:eq(0)').attr('default',true);
    });

    $('#chinese').click(function(){
       $('.player-content-video track').attr('default',false);
       $('.player-content-video track:eq(1)').attr('default',true);
    });
```

---

```
<video class="player-content-video">
  <track src="sample_video-en.vtt" srclang="en" kind="subtitles" default="true">
  <track src="sample_video-ch.vtt" default="false" srclang="ch" kind="subtitles">
  <source src="myvideo.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
<br/>
<button id="turnoff" >NO SUBTITLE</button>
<button id="english" >ENGLISH</button>
<button id="chinese" >CHINESE</button>
```

Comment: @ShijinTR you could please elaborate a little more? Code in my answer change the DOM adding default tag or not depending on what track user select. Please create a full fiddle with your real track, so we can debug your issue properly.

Comment: The DOM was changing ,But the track on the video is not updateing

Comment: @ShijinTR Thanks for reporting, do you have any issues with your track, could you provide a real example? It is difficult to debug your code if we do not have a no access to your tracks. By the way if you think my answer helped you out even partially on your question, please consider up-voting it or accept it :).

Comment: But my issue is with changing the track not with DOM.Is there any way to  use my tracks in this example?